# check if (numberDecimal) edittext is empty/null

Tags: android

My app crashes although the code seems correct :-O if I don't insert anything to editText1 app crashes

```
<EditText
        android:id="@+id/editText1"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
        android:layout_below="@+id/textView1"
        android:layout_marginTop="18dp"
        android:ems="10"
        android:inputType="numberDecimal" >

        String tmp1 = editText1.getText().toString().trim();
                if(tmp1.isEmpty() || tmp1.length() == 0 || tmp1.equals("") || tmp1 == null){
                    editText1.setError("error");
                }
                else
```

Comment: what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: add an error message if editext is empty: setError("error");

Answer (score 2, accepted):

check null first. That is

`if(tmp1==null || tmp1.length() == 0 || tmp1.equals("") || ){
                    editText1.setError("error");
                }`

Answer (score 2):

you need to check if there is anything written in your editText like this

```
if(!editText1.getText().toString().equals("")) {
String tmp1 = editText1.getText().toString().trim();
                if(tmp1 == null || tmp1.isEmpty() || tmp1.length() == 0 || tmp1.equals("")){
                    editText1.setError("error");
                }
}else {
//editText empty
}
```

Comment: also with your code, app crashes: java.lang.NumberFormatException: Invalid double: ""

Comment: Nadir my code works, problem is in another part of code